# Removing an item from a collection after some timeout

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I want is to remove a `Notification` from a `ObservableCollection<Notification>` after some timeout. Is there a better way than starting a new ThreadPool thread for each added item and `Thread.Sleep` in there?

---

**Final code based on *Nidonocu*'s answer:**

```
public class NotificationCollection : ObservableCollection<Notification>
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer;

    public NotificationCollection()
        : this(Application.Current.Dispatcher)
    {
    }

    public NotificationCollection(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        this.timer =
            new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, dispatcher);
        this.timer.Tick += this.TimerOnTick;
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Notification item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        if (!this.timer.IsEnabled)
        {
            this.StartTimer(item);
        }
    }

    private void StartTimer(Notification item)
    {
        var timeout = item.Timestamp + item.Timeout - DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (timeout < TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            timeout = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        this.timer.Interval = timeout;
        this.timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer.Stop();

        this.RemoveAt(0);
        if (this.Count > 0)
        {
            this.StartTimer(this[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't some kind of Timer be more appropriate? You could then just have one thread which if there were more items remaining it would resume the timer and check again a second later if its time for the next notification to be removed.

---

**Edit:**
Since you are in .net 3.5 I am assuming WPF which uses a DispatcherTimer. This will automatically use the correct thread to run the method you pass it as I understand it. Here is UNTESTED code to try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Notification
    {
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class NotificationCollection : ObservableCollection<Notification>
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan timeout;

        private DispatcherTimer timer;

        public NotificationCollection(TimeSpan timeout)
            : this(timeout, Application.Current.Dispatcher) { }

        public NotificationCollection(TimeSpan timeout, Dispatcher dispatch)
        {
            this.timeout = timeout;
            timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, this.Cleanup, dispatch);
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, Notification item)
        {
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Cleanup(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            // Sanity
            if (this.Count == 0)
                return;

            var deadList = from note in this.Items
                           where note.TimeStamp + this.timeout - DateTime.UtcNow < TimeSpan.Zero
                           select note;
            foreach (var note in deadList)
            {
                this.Remove(note);
            }

            if (this.Count > 0)
                timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? All my attempts using only one thread failed, mainly caused by that the items have to be removed in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks. I've modified it a bit and posted the result in the question area.

Answer (score 0):

I would not create a thread for every inserted object.  Instead I would have a single cleanup thread or use a timer object.  When the thread wakes up it can walk through the list cleaning up old items.

I would also overide the index operator and any other accessor methods to not allow items that should be cleaned up but have not yet been.